# An orthogonal git branching strategy

Tags: git

I was reading a note and i came across this term, `orthogonal branch` .. I know that orthogonal literally mean a right angle to one another. This kind of gives an impression that it means, unrelated work on git branches.

The context is ***".....pulls down all Salesforce metadata and commits it to an orthogonal branch in a repository, which can be used for auditing and analysis of how your metadata has changed over time"***

An internet search of this doesn't point to anything with a real description on what is this branching model, rather usage of the term

Comment: Perhaps he wanted to talk about 'orphan branch' (but the extract of text is  it enough to understand)

Comment: The more i read and think, i am almost coming to conclusion that it meant, to be a branch that's not meant to be merged like a traditional feature branch (at-least at the time of its creation).

Comment: It should mean here "unrelated". It is not a term, just human word.